# How to hide stack navigation header from a single screen in react-navigation v6

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am using stack navigation version 5, I need the headers for all screens except one screen, I tried to do this via option inside screens like this:

This is my code:

```js
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const AppStackNavigator = (props) => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ swipeEnabled: false, headerShown: false }}>
      <Stack.Screen name="Start" component={Start} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Welcome" component={Welcome} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
      <Stack.Screen name="SignUp" component={SignUp} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
      <Stack.Screen name="ForgotPassword" component={ForgotPassword} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
      <Stack.Screen name="FavouriteCuisines" component={FavouriteCuisines} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Chef" component={Chef} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}

export { AppStackNavigator }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer is already in your code itself
Just remove all the **headerShown: false** except the one you want to see the headers
See the screen:

```
<Stack.Screen name="Chef" component={Chef} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
```

For any screen, if you want to hide the header just add **headerShown: false** in your options props for other headerShown will be true by default.